# Imitate a low end device

Tags: android, memory-leaks, virtual-machine

So our data shows some crash reports of our app on some low end devices, we know for certain it's  because of memory leak.
Is there any way to imitate that behaviour on pc or some other phone so thay we can fix the issue ?
Or create a VM of a mobile phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the emulators provided with Android Studio. You can easily access to it with menu `Tools > AVD Manager` of Android Studio IDE.

[image: Select AVD Manager]

You can define the device's feature easily.

[image: Hardware profiles]

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a memory leak, imitating a low memory device is not a good way to solve a problem. You can use [LeakCanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary) or [Profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler) from Android Studio to find the leak.

But if you want to emulate device with a low memory then you can use Android Emulator. In AVD (Android Virtual Device) manager you can configure RAM and VM heap in advanced AVD settings.